# Not getting the result as array for PHPUnit object mock

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I am trying to run the unit test by using `PHPUnit` and `Mock` function. I am expecting an array as the result. But always getting an object and that is not related to the function which I called. How can I make this work?

Giving my code below

```
public function testGet()
{
    $mock = $this->createMock(Category::class);

    $map = [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
    ];

    $mock->method('get')
        ->willReturn($this->returnValueMap($map));

    $testVal = $mock->get(1);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($testVal);
    die;
}
```

The result which I am getting from the print is,

```
PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub\ReturnValueMap Object
(
    [valueMap:PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub\ReturnValueMap:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )
```

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 4
            )

    )
)
```

I am expecting to get 2 if I pass 1 to the function and expecting to get 4 if I pass 3 to the function.

The function which I want to test is

`public function get(int $id)
{
    $categoryData = new CategoryData();
    $fields = ['name', 'gid'];
    $getCat = $categoryData->get($id, $fields);
    if ($getCat) {
        return $getCat;
    }
    return [];
}`

**Am I missing something here? Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `->will(` instead of `->willReturn(`, so Phpunit does not return the map object (`willReturn` returns the argument verbatim) but further processes it.

Ref:

- Phpunit 6 documentation: [Example 9.6: Stubbing a method call to return the value from a map](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php)
- PhpUnit 8 documentation: [Example 8.6 Stubbing a method call to return the value from a map](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-stubs-examples-stubtest5-php)